# Hide and Unhide groups of columns in visualforce like excel groups

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I know that you can use the render attribute to hide and unhide groups, but I'm looking for an elegant solution to hide and unhide groups of columns similar to the excel group feature.

Is there good way to do this.  So far all I have is just a couple of links at the top that trigger those true/false on each group.

Comment: So what exactly have you tried? Why doesn't it suit your needs? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Render and rerender is server side logic so it is not quite recommended in this case. You should use javascript and jQuery for this usage. Take a look at this method: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Basically, you need to write a javascript function to handle click event. As below:

```
$("#headerDiv").click(function() {
    $("#contentDiv").toggle();
});
```